# recipe for target 'main.o' failed, Atmel Studio

Tags: c, atmelstudio

I'm getting the error: recipe for target main.o failed. I'm currently programming for the ATmega 168BPB board, trying to run the following simple program:

```
int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    PORTB = 1 << PORTB5;

    while (1) 
    {
    }
}
```

to just get the built-in LED to turn on.
Has anyone had any experience with this problem and/or knows how to solve it?

Comment: I suggest posting the compilation log.  There isn't enough information here to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off your antivirus : i've had that one with "Comodo internet security" After DISABLE "auto-containment", it starts working as expect (with no errors)... if it does any, you probably should add `#include <avr/io.h>` to beginning of your code, this is will declare your CHIP architecture and prevent errors as like `'DDRB' undeclared` and same stuff.

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    PORTB = 1 << PORTB5;

    while (1) 
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this error can be occurred from corruption of header file in windows so reset your windows by saving all of necessary file & reset your windows & agin install microchip stduio there if you run your programme you should not see this error ... i solved my problem by this i hope it will help you guys